# Как разбить дату/время на интервал имея начальное и конечное время

Tags: javascript

Как разбить дату/время на интервал, тоесть есть начальное время и конечное

```
let start = 1595902440886; // начальное время
let end = 1595904296582; // конечное время
```

Нужно в зависимости от диапазона разбить на время, на выводе должно быть в виде массива

Пример:

```
[ 15:00, 15:30, 14:00, 14:30, 15:00 ] // на минуты
[ 1.04.2020, 2.04.2020, 3.04.2020, 4.04.2020, 5.04.2020 ] // на дни
// ... и тд, разные варианты в зависимости от расстояния start и end
```

Это интервал между датами или временем в зависимости от длины, чтобы отобразить после это время на графике

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Примеры интервалы которые есть 2 минуты, 5, 10, 30, 1 час и тд.

Comment: что делать, если начало в 3.17, а требуется каждые полчаса отмечать?

Comment: @MBo, а тут я думаю не важно что в начале, пытаюсь сделать как в обычных графиках, как на tradingview.com например, там чем шире диапазон тем реже дата

Comment: Нет, вопрос в том, ставить первую метку на 3.00, 3.17 или 3.30. И почему вообще такое разбиение нужно делать вручную, если есть библиотеки построения красивых графиков?

Comment: @MBo, на графике получится отобразить только 3.30, получается начало в массиве 3.30 как я понял

Answer (score 5):

Разбиение на метки - элементарно:

```js
function splitInterval(start, end, step) {
  let result = [];

  for (let ts = start; ts < end; ts += step) {
    result.push(ts);
  }

  if (result.length == 1) {
    result.push(end);
  }
  
  return result;
}

// ****************************************

let start = 1595902440886; // начальное время
let end   = 1595904296582; // конечное время
let step  = 2 * 60 * 1000; // шаг в милисекундах (2 минуты)

let result = splitInterval(start, end, step);

console.log('Start: ' + (new Date(start)).toLocaleString());
console.log('End:   ' + (new Date(end)).toLocaleString());
for (let i = 0; i < result.length; ++i) {
  console.log('Step ' + i + ': ' + (new Date(result[i])).toLocaleString());
}
```

Но по вашему ТЗ есть замечания:

1. Первая метка должна начинаться именно со стартого времени. Попытка её округлять приведет к многочисленным логическим проблемам. Подумайте, что если стартовое время у вас 3:14, а длина шага скажем 17 секунд. Тогда где должна быть первая метка? Именно поэтому первая метка должна совпадать со стартовым временем.
2. Ваша основная задача - это разбить любой интервал на метки. Вопрос в каком именно формате выводить эти метки на экран - идивидуален для каждого разбиения. Попытка сделать нечто универсальное приведет к логическим ошибкам. Подумайте что, если интервал у вас скажем более 1-2 суток и вы делите его на шаги длиной в 1 час, а выводите в виде `[01:00:00], [02:00:00], [03:00:00] ...`. Не забывайте также, что в месяцах переменное количество дней, и вывод красивых дат типа `[01.01.2000], [01.02.2000], [01.03.2000] ...` подразумевает переменную длину шагов. Поэтому, окончательный формат метки должен решаться индивидуально для каждого разбиения.

Вообще нормальные библиотеки для работы с графиками устроены так, что им передаются только сырые даные. График строится и отрисовывается по сырым данным. А вот метки форматируются в момент их отрисовки, по формату, который задает пользователь индивидуально.